# WPF usercontrol mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a problem implementing MVVM with a usercontrols.

I have an MVVM based application.

In one of the view (which is a usercontrol) I have a menu on the left and content on the right. The content change depending on the menu.
I tried to implement the MVVM with a usercontrol, but i dont know how.

Here is what i tried but it didn't work :

```
<UserControl x:Class="PoS.Views.OptionsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PoS.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="SettingsTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SettingsViewModel}">
            <views:SettingsView DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I think you need to rewind a bit and read a good book on MVVM before continuing. Gary McLean Hall's `Pro WPF and Silverlight MVVM` is a good place to start.

To answer your question, I'll assume that this user control is set up with its DataContext pointing to your `MainViewModel`. The content on the right needs a corresponding property in the main view model i.e. something like this:

```
private ViewModelBase _CurrentPage;
public ViewModelBase CurrentPage
{
    get { return this._CurrentPage; }
    set
    {
        if (this._CurrentPage != value)
        {
            this._CurrentPage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

You then create a bunch of "pages" or something that inherit `ViewModelBase` i.e. `Page1ViewModel`, `Page2ViewModel`, `SettingsViewModel` etc. You then create a `ContentControl` and bind its content to that property:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
```

So now if your view model does something like `CurrentPage = new SettingsViewModel()` then the `ContentControl` will be populated with whatever you declared as the DataTemplate for that type (i.e. a control of type `views:SettingsView`). If you assign the property to something else then the `SettingsView` will be destroyed and replaced by whatever the DataTemplate for the new type is.

In your example above only SettingsViewModel/SettingsView will work, because that's all you've created a DataTemplate for; in order for this to work you need to create a separate DataTemplate for each ViewModel/View pair type you create.

Comment: I'm interested in the book you recommended, "Pro WPF and Silverlight MVVM," but its reviews on Amazon are not great. If you don't mind, I'd like to know why you think it's a good book.

Comment: Honestly? Because it's the one I originally learned from, and I found it very instructional at the time. Of course, this was some 7 or 8 years ago now, as evidenced by the fact that "Silverlight" is in its title, so maybe there are just a lot of much better options out there now. I also found Josh Smith's "Advanced MVVM" to be worth a read and full of some good practical tips, if a bit on the short side.